# Is it normal that $scope.$digest is not run in production code while unit testing it?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I well know that `$scope.$digest()` is not called automatically when unit testing an AngularJs controller.

However, I have this code in **production** code in one of my controllers:

```
$scope.$digest(function () {
  console.log("should be displayed");
});
```

And the message is never displayed...
When I just drop the wrapper, it works:

```
console.log("should be displayed");
```

Any explanation?

Comment: are you using a minified version of angular in prod?

Comment: Nop, I use the non-minified version (that I compress with Grunt later)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `$scope.$apply` as `$scope.$digest` does not care about what arguments you send in.

See [Documentation for $scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope)

Comment: Wow, indeed that works.. Why $digest has not the same signature? I don't want all my scope hierarchy to be triggered for a digest.

Comment: That's how it's designed, the docs even specify to use `$apply` for the things you are trying to do. `Usually, you don't call $digest() directly in controllers or in directives. Instead, you should call $apply() (typically from within a directive), which will force a $digest().`

Comment: There shouldn't be any noticeable impact on performance between the two.